# Dimensionality Reduction using PCA/SVD

Tags: python, pca

I've just learnt about PCA/SVD and I just wanted to make sure that I've implemented the coding correctly. I also have a little trouble understanding increasing latent dimensionality. Is this another dimension reduction model?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

> Question:
>   For the provided dataset, perform PCA and plot the captured variance with respect to increasing latent dimensionality. What is the minimum dimension that captures (a) at least 95% variance and (b) at least 98% variance?

This is what I did:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca95 = PCA(n_components = 0.95)
pca95.fit_transform(X)
print('95% variance retained = {:1d} 
dimensions'.format(len(pca95.explained_variance_ratio_)))
pca98 = PCA(n_components = 0.98)
pca98.fit_transform(X)
print('98% variance retained = {:1d} 
dimensions'.format(len(pca98.explained_variance_ratio_)))

pca100 = PCA(n_components = 4613)
pca100.fit_transform(X)

fig = plt.figure
plt.plot(pca100.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum())
plt.xlabel('N Dimensions')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Variance Retained')
plt.ylim([0,1.2])
plt.xlim([len(pca100.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()),0])
plt.grid()
```